# Quels mots les français utilisent-ils pour différencier "grass" des herbes culinaires?

Tags: alimentation, botanique

Quels mots les français utilisent-ils pour différencier l'équivalent de *grass* en anglais des herbes culinaires ?

En anglais, les plantes suivantes sont englobées dans le terme générique (umbrella term) "herb":

> - feuilles de basilic italien (albajaka)
> - feuilles de coriandre
> - anis étoilé (estrella de anis, semmulas de anis)
> - églantine (fruit du rosier qui se forme après la chute des pétales)
> - cannelle (canela, cinnamon, ou écorce d'arbre à bonne odeur brune).

les *herbs* sont consommées avec des légumes, des céréales et donc parfois de la viande.

---

***grass*** est utilisée  pour le sport du golf.

## ⛳ ⛳⛳⛳️‍♂️️‍♀️

***grass*** (foin) est également donnée aux <strike>rauques</strike> chevaux et aux vaches.

***grass*** est décorative et n'est pas bonne à manger.

---

[image: a photograph of grass]

[image: a different photograph of grass]

Poa pratensis, communément appelé pâturin des prés (ou pâturin des prés), ou pâturin commun, est une espèce vivace d'herbe originaire de pratiquement toute l'Europe, de l'Asie du Nord et des montagnes de l'Algérie et du Maroc. Bien que l'espèce soit répartie dans toutes les régions fraîches et humides des États-Unis, elle n'est pas originaire d'Amérique du Nord. L'Empire espagnol a apporté les graines de pâturin du Kentucky au Nouveau Monde en mélange avec d'autres graminées.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your question. Rose hip & cinnamon are not "herbs", Rose hip is a fruit, cinnamon is the bark of a palnt. If by  *étoiles d'anis* you mean *anis étoilé*, more commonly called *badiane* in French (*Illicium verum*), it is the seed of the plant and it is not considered as an herb ; anise is an herb (*anis* in French). Grass and herbs are both herbaceous plants. "Grass" is *herbe* in French, and there are lots of them... In English the word "herb" is used for an herbaceous plant that is used for culinary or medicinal properties, *plantes aromatiques* in French.

Comment: *Herbe* is also commonly used in French to designate cannabis (in that case English use the word "weed", even if of course, "weed" is an herb....).

Comment: Watch out, in your questions you often use "y" instead of "et". Confusing with Spanish maybe?

Comment: Aucun animal appelé "rauque" n'existe en français. Je penche pour une faute de frappe suivi d'une traduction automatique (horse->hoarse->rauque).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Le terme **fines herbes** couvre un ensemble de plantes aromatiques du potager utilisées dans la cuisine pour apporter du goût et de la fraîcheur.

Entre autres plantes, le persil, la ciboulette, l'aneth, la sarriette, le basilic, la coriandre, le cerfeuil et la marjolaine font partie de cette catégorie.

Answer (score 6):

En général "l'herbe" désigne les plantes qui recouvre une prairie:

> Les vaches mangent de l'herbe. (Cows eat grass.)

> Faute d'entretien, l'herbe a envahi la cour. (Due to a lack of maintenance, weeds have invaded the courtyard.)

Alors que "les herbes" (au pluriel), désigne des plantes bien identifiées. On peut, pour préciser, parler d'**herbes aromatiques** ou de **fines herbes** pour désigner des accompagnements alimentaires, ou d'**herbes médicinales** pour des plantes qui servent de remède.

Il y a cependant quelques usages figés qui font exception à cela. Par exemple "les herbes folles" est une manière légèrement poétique de désigner une prairie qui a poussé très haut sans être entretenue.

Enfin, "l'herbe" peut-être un euphémisme pour désigner le cannabis.

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a qu'un seul mot. "Herbes" peut désigner les deux types de plantes, comestibles ou non :

> A. − Au sing. et au plur.
>
> 1. Plante phanérogame non ligneuse, annuelle, bisannuelle ou vivace, à tige molle et généralement verte, et dont les parties aériennes meurent chaque année. *Je suis comme une herbe au bord de la route* [...]

> 2. En partic.
>
> - (Fines) herbes. Plantes aromatiques ou condimentaires utilisées pour l'assaisonnement de certains plats. Omelette aux fines herbes. Un arôme de fines herbes, d'épices, de nourriture grasse (Guèvremont, Survenant,1945, p. 116).Condiment aromatique complet remplaçant sel, poivre et vinaigre, il [l'estragon] est utile dans les salades, la laitue notamment dont il relève la fadeur; (...) dans la composition des bouquets garnis dits de « persil » et des fines herbes où il complète si harmonieusement le cerfeuil, la ciboulette ou la pimprenelle (L. Lagriffe, Le Livre des épices, des condiments et des aromates, Les Hautes Plaines de Mane, éd. R. Morel, 1968, p. 187).Des herbes toujours fraîches. *Un bouquet d'herbes est souvent trop important pour être utilisé dans une seule recette*.

Comme le souligne Graffito, on peut utiliser "fines" pour préciser qu'il s'agit d'herbes aromatiques, mais c'est tout à fait optionnel - on considère que le sens peut être deviné d'après le contexte.

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/herbe